# Using methods to create pyramid

Tags: java, methods, turtle-graphics

Ok so my understanding of methods is not at it's best, so I'm here.

So the goal of is to build a pyramid based off a triangle. In drawTriangle I create a triangle, and now I must multiple it one by one for each layer. Top layer would have one triangle...second layer would have two triangles...third would have three...you get the picture.

```
private void drawTriangle () {

  for (int x=0; x<3; x++) { //draws triangle
    yertle.penDown();
    yertle.left(2*PI/3);
    yertle.forward(20); 

  }
}

private void drawPyramind (int n) { //n being layers

  for (int nTri=0; nTri<n; nTri++) { //nTri being copies of triangle
    drawTriangle(nTri); //what I _thought_ would work
    ... //irrelevant code to line up layers
    ... //
  }
}
```

But I'm unsure how I should copy the drawTriangle method into drawPyramid method.

IMPORTANT: However this is an assignment and I don't want a direct answer, just a hint of how I should be doing this to help my understanding of methods.

Comment: you need to create drawTriangle(int triangleOffset), and use the offset to determine the start location of the triangle to draw

Comment: @SeanF see, I would love to add a parameter in drawTriangle, however I am not allowed.

Comment: that is what you are doing here drawTriangle(nTri); //what I _thought_ would work. suggestion was based on what was shown

Comment: @SeanF In hopes that the loop would draw another triangle, however my knowledge on methods is not at the best and I realized that would not work, so I'm unsure how to do this without adding more parameters.

Comment: you want to do something like this in your for loop for (int nTri=0; nTri<n; nTri++) { drawTriangle(); yertle.up(); yutrle.forward(20)} so you draw a triangle, stop drawing, move the starting point then loop again.